# PhpStorm not handling Symfony factory service for Doctrine Repository correctly

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

I have the following service definition for a Doctrine repository in a Symfony project:

```
my_custom_repository_service:
    class: My\Custom\ClassName
    factory_service: doctrine.orm.entity_manager
    factory_method: getRepository
    arguments: [MyCustom:ClassName]
```

When calling this service like this:

```
$repository = $this->container->get('my_custom_repository_service')
```

PhpStorm thinks that `$repository` is `My\Custom\ClassName` instead of the Doctrine repository that it actually is.  Is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `class` attribute of your service to `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`:

```
my_custom_repository_service:
    class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
    factory_service: doctrine.orm.entity_manager
    factory_method: getRepository
    arguments: [MyCustom:ClassName]
```

It really doesn't matter in this case since the repository factory will generate an instance of the class you're passing in as an argument (which should also be a subclass of Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository), but if PHPStorm is picking up on that, this will fix it.

Comment: That method does work when only using the built-in Repository functions like `find` but it doesn't allow me to use code completion for my custom repository class.

Comment: Actually, I just tried making the class name point at my exact repository, and that solved the problem.  Thank you!